# warning "errno" undefined in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a kernel module, and I need to use the `errno` variable.
I included `<linux/errno.h>` with no problems, and added `extern int errno;`,
to my code.

I use the variable in the following way: `errno = ENOENT;`.
When I compile the program I get the following warning, and I cannot load the module:

`WARNING: "errno" [module path] undefined!`

Why is that happening?

I am using a VM of Ubuntu 12.0.4

**EDIT:**
My hooked open syscall looks like this:

```
asmlinkage int hooked_open(char* path, int flags){
   if(strstr(path, file_to_hide) != NULL){
      return -ENOENT;
   }
   return original_open(path, flags);
}
```

When running strace cat file_to_hide when the module is loaded the return value is 4294967294, no error.

When running strace on a file that does not exist, return value is -1 and ENOENT is raised. I would like to be able to imitate that.

Comment: Why do you want `errno`? It is not defined nor used in kernel code.

Comment: I'm hooking a system call (open) and trying to return errors (for hiding the file) for certain inputs.

Comment: @YonatanH `errno` is not used to pass failure reasons from Linux kernel system calls back to user space.  Look at how [`open()` is implemented](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/open.c#L928) for how that's done.

Comment: Kernel module aside, even in ISO C, you should not be declaring `errno` explicitly as `extern int errno`. The appropriate declaration/definition for `errno` is included inside `errno.h` and it _might_ not be `extern int`

Comment: @AndrewHenle I always looked at the implementation of `do_sys_open()` rather that `vfs_open()`. Isn't that the original syscall?

Comment: @Tsyvarev not completely, I'm trying to make sure the output (in strace) is the same when I encounter the file I want to hide. When returning `-ENOENT` I get only 2's complement of -2, and no error code at all.

Comment: @YonatanH That depends on how your kernel module is going to hook the system call. The easiest way is probably a Linux Security Module:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm just a begginer with kernel modules, I'm hooking the syscall by overriding it's address in the syscall table.

Comment: "When returning -ENOENT I get only 2's complement of -2, and no error code at all." - This should work. Probably, you are doing wrong things. Please, **show your code** (add it to the question post).

Comment: @Tsyvarev code added

Comment: Return type for system calls is `long`, not `int`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much! I got confused with the open c command.

Answer (score 1):

From man page of [errno:](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

1. > errno is defined by the ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue        of type int, and **must not be explicitly declared**;
2. > On some ancient systems, <errno.h> was not present or did not
   > declare errno, so that it was necessary to declare errno manually
   > (i.e., extern int errno).  **Do not do this**.  **It long ago ceased to
   > be necessary, and it will cause problems with modern versions of
   > the C library.**

There is no need to explicitly declare `errno`.

Comment: When omitting `extern int errno`, I get `error: errno undeclared`. It wasn't clear from your answer what I should do.

Comment: From man page, it is clear that there is no need to declare again.

Comment: I get `error: errno undeclared` when doing that

Comment: It was already included

Comment: This answer has absolutely no relevance to the use of `errno` in a Linux kernel module implementing a system call.  `errno` is not how Linux system calls return failure reasons back to user space.